# How to use Geoquery on another project with geofire real-time database in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, maps, geofire

I am having 2 firebase project, one for user app and second for the driver app. I am storing the latest location(lat-long) of the driver app on firebase realtime database. Now I want to execute geoquery on driver's project database from my user app. My question is how to execute geoquery on another project. I want to get driver list from user app with the help of geoquery (bypassing the current position of the user to find the nearby driver)

```
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApplicationId("1:my_App_ID").setApiKey("AIza_My_API_KEY").setDatabaseUrl("https://My_URL.firebaseio.com/").build();   
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options);

    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("xyz");
    FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
    DatabaseReference data = secondaryDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drivers Available");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(data);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(21.11626328, 79.051096406), 1);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            Log.d("test_geolocation",key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {}

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {}

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

        }
        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("errorGeoQuery",error+"");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your app instance a name `xyz` if you want to look it up by that name later.

So something like:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApplicationId("1:my_App_ID").setApiKey("AIza_My_API_KEY").setDatabaseUrl("https://My_URL.firebaseio.com/").build();   
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options, "xyz");

FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("xyz");
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [using multiple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application).